# O que é processamento Batch e on-line?

Tags: batch

Batch eu pesquisei e vi que se trata de um processamento em lote.... Ta, mas o que isso quer dizer ?
e o que seria um arquivo batch ? (se refere unicamente à extensão .bat ?)
e o que seriam movimentações batch ?
Qual a diferença de uma movimentação batch para uma movimentação on-line ?

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia!

Processamento em lote significa que é um processamento sequencial, ele só passa para a próxima etapa depois de terminar a etapa atual.

O arquivo ".bat" do windows são scripts em lotes.

A diferença de processamento batch e online é a relação entre o processamento e o registro.

No processamento batch, são feitos todos os processamentos e os registros são salvos em um buffer (algo do tipo). Depois, num determinado momento (no final do dia, no final da semana, no final do mês, em algum horário determinado, etc.) os registros são feitos, na mesma sequência do processamento.

No processamento online, os registros são feitos logo após os respectivos processamentos.

É mais ou menos por aí.

:-)

Answer (score 3):

> [processamento em lote:] o que isso quer dizer ?

É um termo referente a um processamento de dados que ocorre através de um lote de tarefas enfileiradas, de modo que o sistema operacional só processa a próxima tarefa após o término completo da tarefa anterior, de acordo com a [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processamento_batch).

> O que seria um arquivo batch?

Na plataforma Windows um arquivo *batch* é composto por um ou mais comandos que serão executados em ordem.

Em termos gerais, um arquivo batch define um conjunto de dados que irão ser usados em processamento serial.

> O que seriam movimentações batch?

Sem informações complementares, eu imagino que seja uma definição de movimentações (financeiras ou não) que ocorram em processamento serial.

> Qual a diferença de uma movimentação batch para uma movimentação on-line?

On-line se refere ao ambiente de disponibilização, e não quanto ao método de processamento.

Answer (score 3):

Sistemas batch ou sistemas de processamento em lote são um tipo de aplicação que processa uma grande quantidade de dados (lote de dados) durante a sua execução. Eles diferem dos tradicionais sistemas online (web) principalmente nos seguintes aspectos:

1. Interface gráfica: Para interagir com sistemas web utilizamos um navegador web que nos exibe alguma interface gráfica de interação com o sistema. No caso dos sistemas batch, essa interface não existe, o sistema precisa apenas ser executado e não exibe nenhuma informação para usuários.  Pense no sistema batch como aquelas rotinas que as empresas executam mas que os clientes não interagem diretamente com elas (e.g. rotinas de envio de emails com promoções para clientes)
2. Volume de dados: Um sistema web disponibiliza um conjunto de dados restrito para cada usuário. Sistemas batch, por sua vez, costumam processar um conjunto colossal de dados de uma vez só.
3. Natureza do Dado: Para sistemas web, o dado costuma estar disponível naquele momento para ser processado, pois foi fornecido pelo usuário através da interface gráfica do sistema. Já um sistema batch pode ser responsável por processar um dado que ainda não chegou, mas irá chegar de forma agendada.

Quando você menciona uma movimentação online e uma movimentação batch, os termos se referem a dados gerados por sistemas web e batch, respectivamente. Essa dinâmica é comum pois a maioria dos sistemas depende de alguma rotina batch para obter ganhos de performance (batches são otimizados para processamento de grande quantidades de dados).

Se quiser se aprofundar ainda mais, recomendo a leitura [desse artigo do Medium](https://medium.com/@giu.drawer/why-you-should-be-using-spring-batch-for-batch-processing-83f5aafb965f).